# C# Program - Implementing Local Storage to complement SQL Server Storage

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

My team has a tool that we use for storing and analyzing our main product's test data. The test data is stored on an SQL Server by a loader program. We then have a client program that is used to view and analyze the data. The client program queries the database and displays it to the user.

We want to implement a way for the client program to store this information locally without having a server instance or additional software installed. We may need to use the tool on customer computers where can't easily install software (no admin). Thus installing SQL Express locally won't work for our needs. We just want to run the EXE on a PC.

Meanwhile we want to minimize the amount of re-work to enable this capability. Currently the tool queries the DB utilizing a connection string and stores the data into a DataTable object. I doubt it can be as easy as setting up a local object and changing the connection string, but that would be nice. Also, I don't mind changing how the querying works if it allows interfacing with both options. What I'm trying to avoid is having to maintain two completely separate methods for interfacing with the data.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't install the database, then embed it.

Just use the old reliable [SQLite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/?tabs=netcore-cli); export the data you need to a *testdatabase.db* or a *dbgenerator.sql*.

SQLServer dialect and SQLite are for the most part compatible.

And if you're using Entity Framework then just plug in [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli).